# How do I insert multilple rows into a DB2 in one statement?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2

I am using Java and jdbc drivers to establish a connection to a DB2 database. I am attempting to insert multiple Rows into a Table Using a single statement.

Below is my Code:

```
 public void createResources(List<Resources> addedResources)
        throws SQLException{

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null; 
     int i = 0; 

     String values = "INSERT INTO GROUPS (GROUP_NAME, ENTRY_NAME, 
ENTRY_TYPE, LAST_REQ, CREATE_BY, REQ_BY, LAST_CHANGED, LAST_REQ_TIME) VALUES 
 " +  System.getProperty("line.separator");

    while(i < addedResources.size()){

        Timestamp LAST_CHANGED = 
Timestamp.valueOf(addedResources.get(i).getLAST_CHANGED().trim());
        Timestamp LAST_REQ_TIME = 
Timestamp.valueOf(addedResources.get(i).getLAST_REQ_TIME().trim());

        values = values + "('" + 
addedResources.get(i).getGROUP_NAME().trim() + "', '" + 

addedResources.get(i).getENTRY_NAME().trim() + "', '" + 

addedResources.get(i).getENTRY_TYPE().trim() + "', '" +

addedResources.get(i).getLAST_REQ().trim() + "', '"   +

addedResources.get(i).getCREATE_BY().trim() + "', '"  +

addedResources.get(i).getREQ_BY().trim()   + "', '"   +
                                      LAST_CHANGED + "', '"   +
                                      LAST_REQ_TIME + "')," + 
System.getProperty("line.separator"); 


    i = i + 1;
    }   
    values = values.substring(0,values.trim().length()-1);
    Log(Integer.toString(values.length()));
    Log(values);

    try {

         // Get the DB connection
        conn = this.ds.getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        // Prepare the statement and populate with data
        statement = conn.prepareStatement(values);



        // Perform the INSERT operation
        statement.executeUpdate();

        //Commit the changes 
        conn.commit();
        Log("Employee Successfully Added!");
    }
    finally{


        // Any exceptions will be propagated

        // Close database objects, regardless of what happened
        if ( statement != null ) {
            statement.close();
        }
        if ( conn != null ) {
            conn.close();
        }

    }



   }
```

To summarize, I have a loop that iterates through objects in a List and elongates the insert statement until it contains all rows in the ArrayList. I then clean the end of the String when the loop is complete, and attempt to execute the statement.

Here is a sample of how a query statement will look when the method is executed:

```
INSERT INTO GROUPS (GROUP_NAME, ENTRY_NAME, ENTRY_TYPE, LAST_REQ, CREATE_BY, 
REQ_BY, LAST_CHANGED, LAST_REQ_TIME) VALUES 
('JOHN', 'TEST1', 'FILE', 'N/A', 'SSDP071', 'N/A', '2018-09-17 
19:36:34.004', '2018-09-17 19:36:34.004'),
('JOHN', 'TEST2', 'FILE', 'N/A', 'SSDP071', 'N/A', '2018-09-17 
19:36:37.771', '2018-09-17 19:36:37.771'),
('JOHN', 'TEST3', 'FILE', 'N/A', 'SSDP071', 'N/A', '2018-09-17 
19:36:42.021', '2018-09-17 19:36:42.021')
```

My code attempts to execute and throw the following error:

[9/17/18 19:36:42:834 GMT] 00000557 SystemOut                                                    O com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][50053][12311][4.22.37] T2zOS exception: [jcc][T2zos]T2zosPreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_:nativePrepareInto:1583: DB2 engine SQL error, SQLCODE = -104, SQLSTATE = 42601, error tokens = ,;FOR  NOT ATOMIC ERRORCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601

My error token is a comma and I am uncertain which it is referring to. Is there no way to Insert multiple rows into a DB2 Table? Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you _think_ that's how your final statement will look, or did you actually print it out? Did you try copying it from your log and executing it in, say Db2 CLP? Any reason you're not using a parameterized statement?

Comment: Yeah, that's not standard SQL.  Microsoft SQL Server supports that, but I'm fairly sure DB2 doesn't.  You'll have to issue multiple INSERT statements.

Comment: Yes. That statement came from a system out

Comment: One at a time it is. Thanks for the input. New to these things. Was just attempting to verify I was not simply mistyping or misunderstanding the logic

Comment: I am on DB2 Version 12

Comment: You shouldn't be concatenating input values like that to begin with. Use a `PreparedStatement` and `executBatch()` to insert multiple rows

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: the syntax `values (1,2), (3,4)` **is** standard SQL (and has been for ages).

Comment: Please rewrite your code to use parameters. *Never* embed values in a SQL statement. It makes it vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Use `?` placeholders, `setXxx()` and `addBatch()`, then `executeBatch()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use batched statements instead:

```
String values = "INSERT INTO GROUPS " +
"(GROUP_NAME,ENTRY_NAME,ENTRY_TYPE,LAST_REQ,CREATE_BY,REQ_BY,LAST_CHANGED,LAST_REQ_TIME) " +
"VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

// ... 

statement = conn.prepareStatement(values);

// ... 

while(i < addedResources.size()){
   statement.setString(addedResources.get(i)).getGROUP_NAME().trim());
   statement.setString(addedResources.get(i)).getENTRY_NAME().trim());

   // ...  

   statement.addBatch();
}
statement.executeBatch();
```

Comment: This was an effective method. Thanks so much, also thanks for the advice on embedding. I am new to writing programs in my type of environment so I am still learning how to do so in a more secure manner. I will adjust based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the "Driver for JDBC and SQLJ type 2 connectivity" for z/OS, so I will assume that your Db2-server runs on z/OS.

Db2 for z/OS supports multi-row inserts for jdbc, and static-SQL, and dynamic-SQL, and if if have a lot of rows to insert frequently then using multi-row inserts is wise. It uses a different approach than shown in your question (i.e does not use the VALUES clause as you tried).

The driver property `enableMultiRowInsertSupport` is available and should default to enabled. Pay attention to the driver property `atomicMultiRowInsert` if you seek the multi-row insert to be atomic.

Study the jdbc example (at the end of) [this page](https://www.idug.org/p/bl/et/blogid=143&blogaid=369). Refer to the Db2 Knowledge centre for the details of driver settings.